# Calling Python from C# using Pythonnet throws import error

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I have a use case where I want to be able to call a function which is written in Python from my C# code base. When I make a call to this function I want to be able to pass C# types(custom classes) to Python function and for that I was exploring [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet).

Python project has a following sample structure -

```
main.py
service1.py
```

**main.py** has the main function which calls the methods exposed by **service1.py** -

```
from Service1 import MyService1

def Run(a, b):
   service1 = MyService1()
   service1.method(a, b)
```

Now from C# side when I try to execute the Python it is throwing error -

> Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'No module named 'Service1''

C# code -

```
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Program Files\Python39\Python39.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
using (Py.GIL())
{
  using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
  {
     scope.Exec(File.ReadAllText(@"..\Python\main.py"));
   }
 }
```

How do I need to import the required classes correctly?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - .NET assembly doesn't contain MyService1 type. It is there in Python. And I am getting import error for Python type.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I inferred incorrectly that MyService1 was one of the custom C# classes your question talks about. It should have been obvious to me from the beginning, though, as you specifically mentioned the service1.py module. My bad...

Comment: Hmm, the pythonnet documentation is a bit lacking with regard to the PyModule.Exec method. Just a suspicion (i have no evidence, though): Since you create a PyModule by calling Py.CreateScope(), the the directory paths used for module import resolution by that PyModule might not contain the directory with the service1.py file. Since you only pass the main.py script text as a string to the PyModule.Exec script, the PyModule instance has no notion nor knowledge of the existence of the main.py file, and therefore also has no knowledge of the directory path of the main.py file either.

Comment: (2/2) I am of course not sure about it (i am not a user of pythonnet), but perhaps try to find how you could tell the PyModule instance which directories to look into to resolve module imports...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace trying to figure that out :)

Comment: It seems you set a custom PYTHONPATH through the PythonEngine.PythonPath property (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/17296982aa2e0780a09205b36d99d329c4d337f7/src/runtime/PythonEngine.cs#L120-L135) If you are not already playing around with it, perhaps give it try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this issue because my Python scripts were not part of the build folder. I had to ensure that the required Python files are part of the build folder on the successful build of the solution.

To make a file part of your build folder you will need to -
Right click on file in VS -> Properties -> Copy To Output directory -> select Copy Always or Copy if newer.

Alternatively, you can do this from .csproj file as well.